# 'List' object has no attribute 'Values' error

Tags: python, vba, excel

I would like to get the data to Excel worksheet. The problem is when I run the whole code I receive an error but when I run it separately no error it works.

Here is what I want;

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
import requests
import json

payload_city = {'cityId':3969, 'cmd':'districts'}
url = "https://www.garantimortgage.com/apps/Socket/Webservice.ashx"
r_city = requests.post(url, data=payload_city)


data_city = json.loads(r_city.text) #json to python data structure conversion
wb = Workbook()
dict = data_city[:] #translation in to dictionary
for i in list(range(len(dict))):
 print  data_city[i]["DistrictName"]
 payload_district = {'cityId':data_city[i]["CityId"], 'lbDistricts':data_city[i]["DistrictCode"], 'criter':149,'startdate':'2003-01','cmd':'result','areaCode':data_city[i]["AreaWideCode"]}
 
 r_district = requests.post(url, data=payload_district)
 
 data = json.loads(r_district.text)
 data = map(dict.values, data[u'output'][u'resultset'][u'record'][u'data']) #---->NOT OK.
 for row in data:
     Range("A1").value = zip(*data)
```

But when I run this as;

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
import requests
import json

payload = {'cityId':3969, 'lbDistricts':599, 'criter':149,'startdate':'2003-01','cmd':'result','areaCode':18439}
url = "https://www.garantimortgage.com/apps/Socket/Webservice.ashx"
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

wb = Workbook()
#wb = Workbook.caller()
data = json.loads(r.text)
data = map(dict.values, data[u'output'][u'resultset'][u'record'][u'data'])
for row in data:


    Range("A1").value = zip(*data)
```

It works. Could you please tell me where my mistake is? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first code block you have a list named `dict`,  which shadows the built-in `dict` type. So when you try to use the `dict.values` method in

```
data = map(dict.values, data[u'output'][u'resultset'][u'record'][u'data'])
```

Python looks for a `.values()` method in *your* list that's named `dict` instead of using the built-in `dict.values()` method, and it can't find such a method.

So change the name of that list to something that won't clash with a built-in name.

Comment: Thank you, I cant believe i missed that!.

Comment: My pleasure. Think of it as Python's way of encouraging you to not use generic names for your variables. :)