# Altering elements in a python array using the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

**This is for python and the for loop! I am aware you can use other iterations, I would like to know if there is a solution to this problem using the FOR loop.**
I apologise if this a duplicate, I did not know how to phrase the problem to search for it. It is a simple question. 
I like for loops and use them often, but when it comes time to alter the elements as they are iterated, I always seem to have to create a new array with the edited elements. Here is an example:

```
for item in list:
     if item > 7:
          item += 1
```

the item in this case is not returned to the list. I find that I have do something like this:

```
newlist = []
    for item in list:
         if item > 7:
             item += 1
        newlist.append(item)
```

It is not a huge problem, but each time I write out code similar to this I wonder if there is not a simpler way, and one that doesn't create new variables.

*The example above uses built in variable names, it is only an example, and not how anyone should implement a for loop or declare variables*

Comment: don't use keywords as variable names.

Comment: And don't use the names of built-in types like `list`, `str`, `int', `dict`, etc, as variable names, either. [This recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28793202/4014959) is an example of what can happen if you don't follow this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression or a list comprehension to change the original list:

```
lst = [1,3,5,7,8,9,10]

lst[:] = (i + 1 if i > 7 else i for i in lst)

print(lst)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11]
```

Using a list comp:

```
 lst[:] = [i + 1 if i > 7 else i for i in lst]
```

The  `[:]` syntax changes the original list.

It is also more efficient:

```
In [18]: %%timeit
my_list = list(range(10000))
for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
  if item > 7:
    my_list[i] += 1
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.04 ms per loop

In [19]: %%timeit
lst = list(range(10000))
lst[:] = (i + 1 if i > 7 else i for i in lst)
   ....: 

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop

In [20]: %%timeit
lst = list(range(10000))
lst[:] = [i + 1 if i > 7 else i for i in lst]
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop
```

Comment: That works thanks. I have a follow up question, when you say more efficient, you are referring to the use of resources to complete the task right?

Comment: @DaleLudwig, list comprehensions are optimised, a special  `LIST_APPEND` bytecode is generated so we avoid  the overhead of calling the list.append method.

Comment: There is some interesting performance enhancing ideas here https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips

Answer (score 5):

One of the things you can do

```
for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
  if item > 7:
    my_list[i] += 2
```